# creating an excel vba loop to list horizontally, dates between a start and finish date for each set of vertical dates

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I have a list of start and finish dates Cols J & K this list is dynamic. I need to list the individual dates between the two dates to a row (P13) to the right hand side of each set of dates horizontally. The Exit Sub code is to stop the row updating and jump to the next row rather than exiting the sub. I have acheived this for one row, the code I am using is:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim NoDays As Integer

If Range("L13") <> "No" Then
    Exit Sub
End If
StartDate = Range("J13").Value
EndDate = Range("K13").Value
NoDays = EndDate - StartDate + 1
Range("P13").Value = StartDate
Range("P13").Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
    xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False
```

This works for one set.
I have no idea how to loop through each of the sets which could be as many as 12,000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say I knowe exactly what you are after, but this will loop through row 13 to 1000 and process your code.

```
Sub DateThing()
    Dim StartDate As Date
    Dim EndDate As Date
    Dim NoDays As Integer
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 13 To 1000

        If Range("L" & i) = "No" Then

            StartDate = Range("J" & i).Value
            EndDate = Range("K" & i).Value
            NoDays = EndDate - StartDate + 1
            Range("P" & i).Value = StartDate

            Range("P" & i).Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlRows, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= xlDay, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False

        end if

    Next i



End Sub
```

Comment: Ando Spot on, many thanks, I have altered the for I=13 to1000 to a cell reference that counts the number of rows that have numbers in them, so id=f there are more than 1000 lines this will cope. Again many thanks.

Comment: If you are happy then please mark it as the answer. You are very welcome.